# Show missing Sidebar from Gutenberg admin area

Tags: plugins, sidebar, block-editor

I hid the custom sidebar from Wordpress example 
https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/ by pressing remove from toolbar star in the panel. How to get this toolbar again (I can only rename plugin name in the code to see it again)?
It looks like Gutenberg is saving somewhere it's settings. Where?
Thanks

Comment: What's the toolbar star?

Comment: Star beside title which appears in the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No code changes are necessary, it can be done entirely in the UI. Sidebars appear in the 3 dot drop down menu, the star is just a way to add a shortcut to the top toolbar, e.g. here are the Yoast and Jetpack sidebars listed:

[image]

Clicking on those options brings up their sidebars, as well as the unchecked star that can be used to re-add them to the top toolbar. In the image above, I had unchecked the star on the yoast sidebar, just as you had with your own sidebar

**edit**

On further investigation, I've replicated the issue and raised a bug on the Gutenberg repo

I also notice that there's what appears to be a more complete example here:

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/packages/packages-plugins/

So it appears that the handbooks code example is incomplete, and that you need to specify a component of type `PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem` in addition to the sidebar itself in order for it to show up as I described above

```
// Using ES5 syntax
var el = wp.element.createElement;
var Fragment = wp.element.Fragment;
var PluginSidebar = wp.editPost.PluginSidebar;
var PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem = wp.editPost.PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem;
var registerPlugin = wp.plugins.registerPlugin;

function Component() {
    return el(
        Fragment,
        {},
        el(
            PluginSidebarMoreMenuItem,
            {
                target: 'sidebar-name',
            },
            'My Sidebar'
        ),
        el(
            PluginSidebar,
            {
                name: 'sidebar-name',
                title: 'My Sidebar',
            },
            'Content of the sidebar'
        )
    );
}
registerPlugin( 'plugin-name', {
    icon: 'smiley',
    render: Component,
} );
```

Comment: For some reason, I do not see this Plugins section

Comment: I would follow the entire tutorial, that's how it's supposed to work. If you followed the tutorial exactly and yet this isn't happening for you then you need to report that in the Gutenberg repo as a bug

Comment: Additionally, there's no code example in your question, so it's impossible to debug what you've done

Comment: The code is exactly the same (copied) from example

Comment: I found there is already similar or maybe same bug reported:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sidebar-is-not-saving-the-data-like-it-should/

Comment: That's a different issue, I'd go to the gutenberg github repo or the WP Core Trac. My answer describes how it's supposed to work, if that's not how it works for your code then either your code is wrong or the tutorial is wrong/out of date

Comment: Yes, sorry I mistakenly answered as I thought this is the other question I asked... thanky ou for your help, I now understand what was wrong in order to see plugins in the Hide more tools & options menu

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer - settings are hidden in local storage in browser. Deleting it restores the sidebar. If someone knows how to disable this "star" option to hide the panel, I would be grateful